# Designing an express API with user-created custom paths conflicting with other api end points

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, express

In my express app, a user can create a profile, and in doing so can choose a 'CustomUrl' that will be used to generate the url for their profile (example: http://www.myapp.com/profile/customUrl). A profile can also be reviewed, the end points for which might look like:

```
router.get('/reviews', ...) and router.post('/reviews/new',...)
```

The API endpoint for fetching a profile is below:

```
router.get('/:customUrl',...)
```

While I don't think a user would pick a customUrl like 'reviews', it is possible, and as such, my API endpoint to fetch their profile would be intercepted by the route to get '/reviews'.

I have a few ideas, but I'm generally new to Express, and wasn't sure if one way was better than another. Here are some of them:

1) I can put any end-point with a customUrl path above other end points. This doesn't sound acceptable as then the customUrl path would intercept any requests that are meant for '/reviews' etc.

2) I can validate a customUrl that it is not only unique, but is not an existing end point. This does not seem satisfactory as it does not scale well (would have to update the blacklist every time I add a new end point). It would also be problematic if a user has selected a customUrl that I later want to use for another end point.

3) Separate review out of profile and into its own route. This is probably the best solution, although it would present a lot of work that I'm hoping to avoid (there are other sub-routes name-spaced under '/profiles').

4) Put router.get('/reviews'...) above customUrl, but call next() if there is no req.query ('?sortBy=dateCreate' etc).

5) I didn't mention this earlier because it feels like I'd only be hiding the problem instead of fixing it, but my client-side is in React on a separate port, and so I could configure the router to display the url as .com/profile/:customUrl, but change the API end point to be something like: router.get('/',...) with a queryString of '?customUrl=...' or something like that. The url would then be '`www.myApp.com/profile/:customUrl`' but the get request would be to '`api.myApp.com/profile/?customUrl=:customUrl`', and the get request for reviews would be '`api.myApp.com/profile/reviews`' (or something like that).

Anyway, I have a feeling that I'm missing something pretty fundamental. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to be RESTful with your route naming, for example:

- GETing profile:

`router.get('/profile/:customUrl', ...)`

- GETting reviews for a profile

`router.get('/profile/:customUrl/reviews', ...)`

- POSTing a new review (note you don't need a route that says "new" as this can be determined by it being a POST request)

`router.post('/profile/:customUrl/reviews',...)`

You should use the following verbs for the reasons listed if you are being truly RESTful:

- GET - Fetching records
- POST - Adding records
- PUT - Editing records
- PATCH - Performing partial edits (e.g. not sending the whole document)
- DELETE - Removing records

Comment: I see. I've been using .post to cover 'post' requests for updating and deleting, but axios, which I'm using to make AJAX calls, supports patch and delete, as does express router, so I'll change those end points to reflect that. In the case where I am using an end point to get all reviews (not just those for a specific profile), should I break reviews out of /profile/ and make a separate route? All reviews must be approved before being posted, and as such, there is a page which GETs all reviews with a status of 'pending.' Right now, that end point is router.get('/profile/reviews',...).

Comment: See my edit above for a list of verbs and what you should use them for

Comment: Thank you very much. I've upvoted your answer, but since I'm new to stackoverflow, and have a reputation below 15, it doesn't display. I also edited my comment regarding the profiles (see the last sentence). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: In the case of seeing all reviews, it comes down to your choice ultimately, you could break reviews out completely to its own entity (e.g. '/reviews/:customUrl') rather than being tied to a profile, then to get them all you just don't pass the customUrl param in.